# Matching search term and surrounding text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, regex, dataframe

am fairly new to Python after my Amnesia.

The goal is to match some text inside text I get from a dataframe e.g. df['tweet'], but to return the full text in case I find the queried search term inside it.

I try to return the (same) full text per tweet, of that tweet per row when the search term matches the text I'm looking for in the tweets.

This is what I have, and what would be your approach?

This first regular expression matches URLs and works as expected. I want to know how to match the RegEx in "hit2" and return the words, before and after the match, and also the match.

```
# match URLs
def hit1(text):
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', text)
    if not urls:
        print("Variable is empty")
    else:
        return urls


# match search term *text* + "intelligence" + *text*
def hit2(text):
    intel = re.findall(r'[^(.*?)intelligence]', text)
    if not intel:
        print("Variable is empty")
    else:
        return intel
```

Then

```
# apply functions

urls = []
intels = []

for i in range(0, len(data['tweet'])):
    urli = hit1(data['tweet'][i])
    if not urli:
        continue
    else:
        urls.append(urli)


for i in range(0, len(data['tweet'])):
    inteli = hit2(data['tweet'][i])
    if not inteli:
        continue
    else:
        intels.append(inteli)
```

Then when I need the text further down the line, it will come out garbled?

What I really would like to see is a df['urls'] and df['intelligence'] output.

**All that I get right now is output like 't', 'w', 'e', 'e', 't'... instead of "tweet".**

Thanks, super!

Comment: could you provide a sample of what is inside the dataframe i.e., inside data['tweet']?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to tweak the regex a bit for `hit2`, and return [.group()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.group) to get it back as a single string. Also, `apply` makes it easier to perform the operation on the dataframe rather than using a for loop. Finally, use `to_list()` to get the result into a list.

```py
# match search term *text* + "intelligence" + *text*
def hit2(text):
    intel = re.match(r'^(.*?)intelligence(.*?)$', text)
    if intel:
        return intel.group()
    return text

intels = df['tweet'].apply(hit2).to_list()
```